# Can't Display my HTML content on TinyMCE Text Area

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce, rich-text-editor, html-to-text

I am trying to create a rich text editor on my application's modal by using tinymce instead of text area. But my HTML code can't be displayed as a text on rich text's content area. I am using Angular 2.

Any help would be appriciated

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 'angular2/core';
import { RdComponent, RdLib } from '../../../../../node_modules/mulberry/core';

declare let tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'mail-template',
  template: `
            <textarea style="height:15em"><p>{{ content }}</p></textarea>            
            `
})
export class MailTemplatesComponent extends RdComponent {

  @Input("rd-model") model: string;

  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public editor: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.model);
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        })
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
   <rd-field [rd-text]="translate('Mail İçeriği')"></rd-field>
   <mail-template [(rd-model)]="data.MailContent" rd-height="25em"></mail-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that {{ content }} is not displayed inside of the textarea? Probably tinymce is overwriting the content of textarea and Angular loses context to it.

Comment: Btw content is not even defined as a class variable. So {{ content }} is undefined. Im not 100% sure what you are trying to archive anyway.

Comment: @Mick  thanks to you I have solved the problem. The problem was, I did not see that I needed to use {{model}} instead of {{content}} to get HTML content into the rich text area. Thank you.

Comment: I have found a best solution for problem and I think it would be helpfull for the people who experiences the same problem. http://estynedwards.com/blog/2015/12/04/getting%20started%20with%20angular%202/

Answer (score 0):

**I am using angular2-froala-wyswiyg**

> this is the best i could find and easy to use (link below)

https://libraries.io/npm/angular2-froala-wyswiyg#usage

```
npm install angular-froala-wysiwyg --save
npm update froala-editor --save
```

**package.json (file)**
after the installation of module

```
  "dependencies": {
    .....
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.2",
    ...
}
```

**Imports in your module**

```
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
...

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(), FroalaViewModule.forRoot() ... ],
   ...
})
```

**angular-cli.json(file)**
make changes in styles and scripts as shown below

```
 "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"
  ],
```

**In your component template**

```
 <textarea class="form-control" [froalaEditor] name="x" #x="ngModel [(ngModel)]="obj.name" required ></textarea>
```

[image]
**After editing display it as**

```
<span [innerHTML]="obj.name"> </span>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I have already check the angular2-froala-wyswiyg and other rich text  editors. But unfortunately in my current project it is not working. Only TinyMCE is woking perfectly.